# R logical issue: longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length ( dplyr::if_else() )

Tags: r, performance, if-statement, dplyr, logical-or

I am not sure how I can modify my code by using another method than `if_else()` and keep its efficiency. Here is a simple example of my original code:

```
library(dplyr)

# The goal is to know between which threshold belongs each record
data <- c(runif(99999), NA)
threshold <- seq(0, 1, by=0.1)
rank <- if_else(is.na(data), NA, max(which(data >= threshold))) # Error: longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Thanks you

Comment: `data` and `threshold` need to be of the same length to compare them. What are you trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `if_else` isn't the right function here. Try with `findInterval` or `cut` which will find the right bucket of `threshold` in which your `data` lies.

```
findInterval(data, threshold)
```

With `cut`

```
cut(data, threshold)
```

Use `cut` with `labels = FALSE` if you want to get the `threshold` index

```
cut(data, threshold, labels = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. You were right and I used your first solution.